# isomorphism between factor ring of matrices and Z

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

I have a commutative ring R= $\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ 0 & a \end{pmatrix}$ (R is a 2x2 matrix, a, b $\in$ Z), I=$\begin{pmatrix}0 & b \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ is an ideal.

I need to prove that R/I is isomorphic to Z.

I was trying to show that I is a maximal ideal but couldn't figure it out properly. Anyone, please, help. 
or I should be prime…

Comment: I believe it is implicit in your question, but you should mention that the elements $a$ and $b$ belong to $Z$.

Answer (score 3):

We can use the first isomorphism theorem to prove this.

Let $\phi : R \to \mathbb{Z}$ denote that mapping $\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\ 0&a \end{pmatrix} \to a$. It can be shown that $\phi$ is a homomorphism.

Then $\ker \phi = I$. And $\phi (R) = \mathbb{Z}$.

This is all we need for the first isomorphism theorem to say $R/I \cong \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I did it the same way, but the professor, who assigned this problem, wants it to be solved through maximal/prime ideals. That's where I got stuck…

Comment: Hint: $I$ cannot be maximal since $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field, but $I$ has to be prime since $\mathbb{Z}$ is an integral domain. Of course this is only known after the theorem is proven -- but it may provide some direction.

Comment: Is there a way to prove that I is prime? Then by theorem R/I will be an integral domain as well..

Comment: Look at two elements of $R$, say $\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\ 0&a \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} c&d\\ 0&c \end{pmatrix}$. Suppose their product is in $I$. Then, if you multiply them, you get that $ac = 0$, so either $a$ or $c$ is $0$. Thus, one of them is in $I$. That proves that $I$ is prime.

Comment: That is what I am currently trying to figure out. It is easy enough to show that $R/I$ is an (infinite) integral domain with characteristic $0$. I suppose one could look up the basic axioms of the integers and show that $R/I$ follows them. See http://www.math.niu.edu/~jthunder/Courses/2009Fall/420/sec1/aug24/intaxioms.pdf. (this doesn't use prime ideals either . . .)

Comment: I was thinking maybe because the entries of R/I would be integers that somehow leads that the whole int.domain is isomorphic to Z..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11812/discussion-between-eric-thoma-and-nika)